# Power button doesn’t seem to work

Tags: ipad

I have a 1st or 2nd generation iPad and it’s been charging in the wall for more than 24 hours but all I get is the Apple logo. My power button seems stuck as well, It doesn’t move when you press it. I have tried to plug it into my computer to do the reset but it doesn’t appear on my iTunes so I wasn’t able to go that route. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help but sometime device may get into a weird state. Have you try a hard reset? i.e., holding down power and home button for 10 seconds -- the screen should go blank and then show the Apple logo, that's where you can release the button.

Comment: I would second that if you haven't already tried a hard reset, also worth doing it while charging.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the device is quite old, possibly that the battery in the device has failed.

You should first check you are using a 10W iPad charger, but if that still doesn't work after an hour or two of charging it is time to look for a replacement battery.

You should first check your service options with Apple:
https://checkcoverage.apple.com/

However given the age of the device even if they would service it (which is unlikely) then the cost would be prohibitively expensive.

In this case you could look at a DIY battery replacement there are instructions on sites like iFixIt, or through a local phone repair shop.